# subset structured array based on column names

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, subset

I have a structured array created from a CSV file.

I have many fields/columns. I would like to create a subset array.

`z=mydata[['z1','z2','z3']]` will do the trick, but sometimes `z` goes from `z1-z2` only or `z1-z10`.

Is there an easy way to subset all columns where the column name starts with z regardless of how many columns are in the data? Obviously the resultant array will have different number of columns but that's fine.

Comment: Can you give us some more examples? It rather unclear from what you've given us so far.

Comment: Depending on the data set I am reading from the CSV, I may have columns z1, z2, z3 but in another case it might be z1,z2,z3,z4,z5. I want to create the array z that always subsets all columns from mydata that starts with a 'z'. I.e. I do not have to keep changing the statement z=mydata[['z1','z2','z3']] or z=mydata[['z1','z2','z3','z4','z5']]  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pretty, but you can do the following:

```
z = mydata[[x for x in a.dtype.names if 'z' in x]]
```

Effectively you loop through all of the column names and check if the column name matches the criteria. If there is a better way I would be very interested as I do similar operations in pandas using the `pd.DataFrame.columns` attribute.

Comment: That easy! Thank you!

Comment: @Ophion: for the pandas version you can do things like `df.columns.to_series().str.startswith("Z")`, but to be honest I often use the listcomp anyway as it's more robust.